# Let $R$ the region of the plane specified by $R=\{(x,y)\mid a_1x\le y^2\le a_2x, b_1x^2 \le y \le b_2x^2\}$

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, definite-integrals

Let $a_1,a_2,b_1 \text{ and } b_2$ real constant  such that $0<a_1<a_2$ and
 $0<b_1<b_2$ and let $R$ the region of the plane specified by  $R=\{(x,y)\mid a_1x\le y^2\le a_2x, b_1x^2 \le y \le b_2x^2\}$.

Show that $$\iint _R \left(\frac{y}{x^2}\right)^3 \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y=\frac{1}{6}(a_2-a_1)(b_2^2-b1^2)$$

I'm using Wolfram to solve the problem

[Wolfram's solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%200%3Ca%3Cb,ax%3Cy%5E2%3Cbx,0%3Cr%3Cp,rx%5E2%3Cy%3Cpx%5E2%20,%20for%20y,x)

where $a=a_1 , b=a_2 ,r=b_1 \mbox{ and } p=b_2$

I have three different cases and with this help is possible solve the problem, but my conscience tell me "You're cheating" :(

Any hint or help??

Thanks for your help :D, have a nice day.